# HTML5 cache manifest only caches once

Tags: html, caching, joomla3.4

I created a web app that caches certain pages in case the user needs to view parts of the site offline. The web app should **always be using the most recent files** when viewed.

When the user views the website for the first time, it will cache for them. My issue is that it **only caches the first time.**

According to the documentation, the cache should update based on changing the manifest file itself, but this doesn't seem to function as it should.

Here is the standard layout i'm using. I've been testing with solely index.html to get it working. **I change the version number to update it**, but i've tried changing other parts as well:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Version 0.0.11
# Change the version every time the cache should be renewed.

# List the cached files 
CACHE:
index.html

# Says which url’s to prefer loading from online if available. ("*" = All URL's)
NETWORK:
*
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
       Test 1
    </body>
</html>
```

I update both the cache manifest and the body of the index.html to test if it functions properly. But it looks like the application cache is only grabbing it the first time, and doesn't recognize the updates.

What could be causing it to recognize to cache once, but not update based on the cache manifest number?

**UPDATE** it works in every browser except firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It was the fact that I was using .manifest rather then .appcache at the end of my manifest file. I didn't think it would be that much of an issue, but it makes sense.